# Display Inventory in Powershell (Help)

Tags: powershell

I'm working in a script to generate a report of the inventory in my work.
Most part of the script is working fine, but I'm having problems to get monitor size in inches correctly.

How can I get these values in my current script?

```
$ManufacturerHash = @{
"AAC" = "AcerView";
"ACR" = "Acer";
"ACI" = " Asus";
"APP" = "Apple Computer";
"AUO" = "Asus";
"CMO" = "Acer";
"CPQ" = "Compaq";
"DEL" = "Dell";
"HWP" = "HP";
"LEN" = "Lenovo";
"SAN" = "Samsung";
"SAM" = "Samsung";
"SNY" = "Sony";
"SRC" = "Shamrock";
"SUN" = "Sun Microsystems";
"SEC" = "Hewlett-Packard";
"TAT" = "Tatung";
"TOS" = "Toshiba";
"TSB" = "Toshiba";
"VSC" = "ViewSonic";
"UNK" = "Unknown";
"_YV" = "Fujitsu";
}

Write-Host "##Monitors##"  -ForegroundColor Green
$displayDevices = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\WMI -Class WMIMonitorID
$DisplayParams = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\WMI -Class WmiMonitorBasicDisplayParams

foreach ($displayDevice in $displayDevices) {
        If ([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($displayDevice.UserFriendlyName) -ne $null) {
            $displayModel = ([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($displayDevice.UserFriendlyName)).Replace("$([char]0x0000)","")
        } else {
            $displayModel = $null
        }

    $displaySerial = ([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($displayDevice.SerialNumberID)).Replace("$([char]0x0000)","")
    $displayManufacturer = ([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($displayDevice.ManufacturerName)).Replace("$([char]0x0000)","")

    $displayManufacturerFriendly = $ManufacturerHash.$displayManufacturer 

        If ($displayManufacturerFriendly -eq $null) {
            $displayManufacturerFriendly = $displayManufacturer
        }

   $MaxHorizontalImageSize = [System.Math]::Pow($monitor.MaxHorizontalImageSize, 2)
   $MaxVerticalImageSize = [System.Math]::Pow($monitor.MaxVerticalImageSize, 2)
   $inches= [System.Math]::Round(([System.Math]::Sqrt($MaxHorizontalImageSize + $MaxVerticalImageSize)/2.54))

   Write-Host "Manufacturer:"$displayManufacturerFriendly 
   Write-Host "Model:"$displayModel
   Write-Host "Serial:"$displaySerial
   Write-Host "Size: $inches inches"
   Write-Host ""
```

Comment: Check your variable names, in your first step you are using $monitors (plural) in your calculation you are using $monitor (singular).

Comment: PLEASE, fix your code formatting. right now it is nearly unreadable. [*sigh ...*]

Comment: Sorry, this is my first question here. Now code formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been mentioned in the comments, you never seem to define `$monitor` anyway.

You can grab the appropriate monitor by correlating the `InstanceName` property of both classes:

```
$monitor = $monitors.Where({$_.InstanceName -eq $display.InstanceName})
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.